# How i can have control on calendar view in mantine datepicker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mantine

How i can have control on calendar view? like in this video (this date picker create with react-day-picker)

You can find video about this on here: https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine/issues/5352